# Узнать, какие изображения присутствуют на другом изображении

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения

Прошу помощи в поиске подходящего решения для моей задачи. Пытаюсь написать скрипт для неких целей, многое перепробовал, но ничего стоящего сделать не удалось. Сразу к делу.

Входные данные: широкое изображение с небольшой высотой (назовем его лентой), которое состоит из помех (ненужных частей) и других изображений одинаковых размеров, которые, нужно распознать. Лента может иметь разный размер. Несколько примеров ленты:

[image: Несколько примеров ленты]

Помехи на ленте могут быть как и между изображениями, так и на краях изображений.

На компьютере имеется папка с картинками. Примерно так выглядят эти картинки:

[image: Так выглядит папка с картинками]

Эти картинки являются центральными частями изображений из ленты. На этих картинках не может быть помех, так как отсутствуют края оригинальных изображений, которые показываются на ленте (как раз на этих краях и могут быть помехи). Так нагляднее:

[image: Где могут быть помехи, а где нет]

Так вот. После того, как скрипт принимает ленту как входные данные, на выходе он должен вернуть имена тех картинок, которые соответствуют изображениям на ленте. То есть вот это:

[image: Пример входных данных]

Должно вернуть это: `bird3.png, bird6.png, bird5.png, bird4.png`.

Как можно решить эту задачу? Упор должен быть в скорость обработки, но это не слишком критично. Для обработки ленты из 10 изображений должно (желательно) хватать 2 секунд. Лента не может быть слишком огромных размеров, т.к. максимальный размер одного изображения в ленте - это центр (картинка из папки) + недостающие края (~300x150).

P.S. Я не прошу написать весь скрипт за меня, мне нужно знать только в сторону чего смотреть, какие инструменты и библиотеки использовать, etc.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [How does ImageMagick's '-subimage-search' operation work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29062811/4279)

Comment: @jfs Находил этот вопрос, но смутила вот эта строчка в ответе: `Warning: Conducting a subimage-search is slow -- extremely slow even.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону искусственных нейронных сетей. На просторах интернета много примеров создания нейросетей для работы с изображениями, в том числе на [Geektimes](https://geektimes.ru/hub/artificial_intelligence/). При их использовании можно добиться желаемой для вас скорости обработки, так как нейронные сети обрабатывают данные параллельно.

Литература для начала:

[В.А. Головко "Нейронные сети: обучение, организация и применение"](http://lux.booksee.org/book/1506546)

[Саймон Хайкин "Нейронные сети: полный курс, 2-е издание"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=LPMr0iA0muwC&pg=PA691&hl=ru&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Для работы с нейронными сетями на Python есть отличная библиотека с открытым исходным кодом [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/).